# [R]Can this for loop with multiple ifs be vectorized?

Tags: r

[noob alert]I just learned a bit about vectorizing and its effect in code run times in R, so it came to my mind to try to vectorize my old codes if possible.
I have a for loop using multiple IFs, as a result quite slow. Can this be vectorized?

```
for(i in 1:nrow(merge24)){
  if(is.na(merge24$Paid.Avg.x[i]) & is.na(merge24$Paid.Avg.y[i])){
    merge24$Tot.Paid.Avg[i] = NA
  }
  else if(is.na(merge24$Paid.Avg.x[i])){
    merge24$Tot.Paid.Avg[i] = merge24$Paid.Avg.y[i]
  }
  else if(is.na(merge24$Paid.Avg.y[i])) {
    merge24$Tot.Paid.Avg[i] = merge24$Paid.Avg.x[i]
  }
  else {
    merge24$Tot.Paid.Avg[i] = (merge24$Paid.Avg.y[i] +merge24$Paid.Avg.x[i])/2
  }
}
```

Comment: I did try to vectorize this, but couldnt think of any way as different if statements are checking for different criteria.

Comment: please provide a reproduicle example. `?dput` should help

Comment: try `rowMeans(merge24[c("Paid.Avg.x", "Paid.Avg.y")], na.rm=TRUE)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pierre said with `data.table`

```
merge24 <- data.table(merge24)
merge24[, .(Paid.Avg.Tot = rowMeans(.SD, na.rm=TRUE)), .SDcols = c("Paid.Avg.x", "Paid.Avg.y")]
```

Comment: I like data.table but don't expect this to be faster.